# I have an enum, but i dont know how can I use correctly?

Tags: java, oop, enums, java-8

I searched so long for what enums are useful. In my Opinion there are Variables with many keywords. So have to programming a program what Is used to manage a bank. My Enum has 2 Variables EINZAHLUNG(Deposit) and AUSZAHLUNG(Payout).

```
public enum Transaktionsart {
    EINZAHLUNG,AUSZAHLUNG;
}
```

So I have an class Menue which is provide to call the Methods. The menue would be chosen by an UserInput.

```
public class Menue {
    public void auswahlMenue() {        
        String auswahl;
        do {
            menuePunkte();
            auswahl = MeineEingabe.erfasseAuswahl("Auswahl: ");
        
            switch (auswahl) {
                case "10":
                    geldEinzahlen();
                break;
                case "11":
                    geldAbheben();
                break;
                case "15":
                    System.out.println("Das Programm wurde Beendet!!");
                break;
            }
        } while (!auswahl.equals("15"));
    }
}
```

The method geldEinzahlen() Pays the desired amount to the account. EINZAHLUNG. This would be change the ArrayList, but first I want to know why I should use enum.

```
public void geldEinzahlen(){
    
    System.out.println("Ihr aktueller Kontostand betreagt: " +    konto.getKontoStand() +"€");
    double betrag = MeineEingabe.erfasseDouble("Wie viel wollen sie Einzahlen? ");
    System.out.println(konto.getKontoStand() + betrag);
}
```

The method geldAbheben() is used to pay a fee from the account. The account cant be under 0€. This would be change the ArrayList, but first I want to know why I should use enum.

```
public void geldAbheben(){
    
    double betrag = MeineEingabe.erfasseDouble("Wie viel wollen Sie abheben? ");

    if(konto.getKontoStand() > betrag){
        
    }
    else if (konto.getKontoStand() < betrag){
        System.out.println("Leider koennen Sie diesen Betrag nicht auszahlen");
    }
}
```

I have csv.file but I think that is it not so important.

So the teacher wants that I use a enum but in my Opinion it is really useless. I want to ask the community of Stack Overflow. What can I write for example that I have usage of enums.

Comment: basically with [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) you could replace your `case "10":` with something like `case Transaktionsart.EINZAHLUNG:`. read the docs for more info though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the great point of enums. Enum can contain implementation, so using enum avoids any need of writing switch/case structure at all.

Let me give you and example. Please excuse me, but I am going to use English in names of identifiers.

```
public enum Transaction {
    DEPOSIT {
        @Override public void perform(double amount) {
             // code that puts amount to deposit
        }
    },
    PAYOUT {
        @Override public void perform(double amount) {
             // code that pays specified amount 
        }
    },
    ;
    public abstract void perform(double amount);
}
```

Now it is very easy to use this code:

```
......
Transaction.valueOf(transactionName).perform(amount);
.......
```

Where `transactionName` and `amount` can be parameters.

Comment: Transaction::perform can also be implemented by having a constructor that accepts a DoubleConsumer so that it delegates to said consumer once perform() is called: public enum Transaction { DEPOSIT(amount -> {/*deposit*/}), PAYOUT(amount -> {/*deposit*/}); private final DoubleConsumer performer; public void perform(double amount) { performer.accept(amount); } private Transaction(DoubleConsumer performer) { this.performer = performer; } }

Comment: @srborlongan, java is a general purpose programming language. There are a lot of solutions for any problem. I just wanted to explain the point of enums by simple example.

Comment: I think, what’s missing here (which might look too obvious to you, but to the OP it isn’t), is that the two methods `geldEinzahlen()` `geldAbheben()` can be replaced by *one* method receiving the desired `Transaction` as parameter. So this method can do all the things that are common, i.e. printing the old balance and asking for the transaction amount, before doing that single thing that is different, i.e. by delegating to the `perform` method of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative implementation of @AlexR's answer, using DoubleConsumers to contain the Transaction::perform implementation for each enum:

```
public enum Transaction {
  DEPOSIT(amount -> {
    // deposit
  }),
  PAYOUT(amount -> {
    // payout
  });

  private final DoubleConsumer performer;

  public void perform(final double amount) {
    performer.accept(amount);
  }

  private Transaction(final DoubleConsumer performer) {
    this.performer = performer;
  }
}
```

Used in the exact same way as @AlexR's answer:

```
.....
Transaction
  .valueOf(transactionName)
  .perform(amount)
;
.....
```

Comment: I just change the menue as enum. I think thats ok